# Any way to call a javascript function after Svelte #await :then

Tags: javascript, svelte

Is there any way to call a javascript function after Svelte `#await :then`? What I wanted to do in following code is call a javascript table once I created empty Datatable with some id and then in the javascript just add the data in the Datable. So, basically I wanted to pass `data1` in the javascript function and the id of the DataTable or dataTable element itself. Is there any way I can do this?

```
<div>
  <h1> Title</h1>
  {#await promise}
    loading...
  {:then data}
    {#each data as data1, i}
      <DataTable id={data1.title}/>
      <br />
      ---> I want to call javascript function here which would add data in the given data table. How can I do that?
    {/each}
  {:catch error}
    <kat-alert header="Error" description={error.message} variant="warning" />
  {/await}
</div>
```

Comment: Simple trick if you want to modify the data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66080028/9157799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if the `DataTable` you are creating is supposed to take in the data, why not simply pass it to it ?

```
{#each data as data1, i}
   <DataTable id={data1.title} data={data1.actualdata}/>
{/each}
```

Alternatively, you could add an event to the component itself.

```
{#each data as data1, i}
   <DataTable id={data1.title} use:fillTable{data1, data1.title}></DataTable>
{/each}

<script>
  const fillTable = (el, data, id) => () => {
     // el would be the created element
     // data and id were passed on in the #each
  }
</script>
```

A third way would be to move the promise out of the markup and put the logic in the script tag itself, it would require using some extra variables to track the loading, error, etc... but might end up being cleaner if you want to add a lot of extra actions related to the promise resolution itself. I suppose there it becomes more a matter of taste.